# Solidity try catch always throws in foundry

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to write a validation function in solidity. However my foundry test always throws.

This is the problematic code.

```
function _isERC721(address tokenAddress) internal view returns (bool) {
    //TODO: we need to handle this properly, as there are potential collision if a the NFT contract wants to create 
    // access and their id's are 0 based for the nft's
    try IERC165(tokenAddress).supportsInterface(type(IERC721).interfaceId) returns (bool isNFTAddress) {
        return isNFTAddress;
    } catch {}
    return false;
}

function _isAccountOwner(AuthorizationKey calldata accountKey, address thirdParty) internal view returns (bool) {
    //TODO: we need to handle this properly, as there are potential collision if a the NFT contract wants to create 
    // access and their id's are 0 based for the nft's
    if(_isERC721(accountKey.authAddress)) {
        return IERC721(accountKey.authAddress).ownerOf(accountKey.id) == thirdParty;
    } else if(accountKey.authAddress == thirdParty) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If I comment out the try catch everything works fine.  However when I don't the foundry test reverts.

I have a feeling this is related to foundries implementation.

How can I test code in foundry, which contains a try catch?